# Force unobstructive syntax without Html.BeginForm / Ajax.BeginForm in partial view

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, partial, unobtrusive-javascript

When I put a part of my form in a partial view, all form parts get unobstructive syntax except the form elements in the partial view.

The only way I found how to "apply" the unobstructive syntax, is by starting another form inside the partial view.

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitHandler", new DefaultAjaxOptions()))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model)
}
```

PartialView:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeContent)
```

Output:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
<input id="SomeContent" name="SomeContent" type="text" value="0">
```

So only the input element from the View has the unobstructive syntax and the partial view hasn't...

Is there a way to apply unobstructive syntax inside a partial view, wich doesn't require you to begin a new form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found a better solution! Went digging a bit in the asp.net mvc code and the MvcForm class creates all the unobstructive validation syntax.

so if you use:

```
@using(new MvcForm(ViewContext))
{
}
```

instead of

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

it will still apply the unobstructive syntax, but won't create the form html tags :)

Comment: how did you solve it , i'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @Aravind you should wrap your partial cshtml file with:
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
content..
}
in this way you will get all correct html attributes without it being wrapped in a <form> tag :)